# How to factor in decimals when using division and remainders

Tags: solidity

math is not my strong suite so I have a question for anyone that understands solidity's mathematical operations.

_

I have the following situation:

- Token is priced at 0.001 Ethereum.
- Token has 18 decimals.

### Example purchase A (code at the bottom):

- Person A deposits 0.01 Ethereum.
- Amount deposited divided by price is 10.
- So Person A gets 10 tokens, but we have 18 decimals. So it should be 10e18, not 10. How do we get this? (see code)

_

## Example purchase B (code at the bottom)

- Person B deposits 0.0001 Ethereum
- Amount deposited divided by price should be 0.1 if done on a calculator, but a simple division in solidity only returns 0. I understand this is due to solidity not denoting decimals by a dot notation, so the answer should ultimately become 1e17

### Code situation A

```
 function FooBar() public returns (uint){
    // 1 Token will cost 0.001 eth.
    uint256 _tokenPrice = 1e15;

    // Incoming ethereum is 0.01.
    uint256 _ethereumSent = 1e16;

     // This should net us 10 tokens.
    uint256 _totalTokens = _ethereumSent / _tokenPrice;

    // So this returns 10, but we want 1e19 because of the fact that our token has 18 decimals.
    return _totalTokens;
}
```

Code situation B

```
 function FooBar() public returns (uint){
    // 1 Token will cost 0.001 eth.
    uint256 _tokenPrice = 1e15;

    // Incoming ethereum is 0.0001.
    uint256 _ethereumSent = 1e14;

     // This should net us 0.1 tokens.
    uint256 _totalTokens = _ethereumSent / _tokenPrice;

    // So this returns 0, but we want 1e17 because of the fact that our token has 18 decimals.
    return _totalTokens;
}
```

How do I get the desired results? Thanks in advance, I'm more then willing to provide any additional information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to achieve can be done by including the actual decimal places to `_ethereumSent`.

Replace `_totalTokens` with this:

```
uint256 _totalTokens = (_ethereumSent * 10**18) / _tokenPrice;
```

or this if you prefer scientific notation:

```
uint256 _totalTokens = (_ethereumSent * 1e18) / _tokenPrice;
```

`1e18` or `10**18` represents the number of decimals to your token.

You should get the right answer for each scenario and the right amount of tokens based on the decimal value.

---

The overall theme when it comes to doing math in solidity is...always multiply the numerator by the squared amount of precision needed and account for that in your code.